# https sites not loading with React Native Expo 32 WebView

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I have an RN Expo app on Expo v30 that loads https URLs with no problem, but after upgrading to v32 the same URLs do not load.

No error in the console, just the loading spinner shown indefinitely.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: There is no problem with expo version 32. It works normally.

Comment: Don't you get an error if you remove the loading spinner setting?